# OpenCV forEach with two cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to perform a pixel-by-pixel operation between 2 images in OpenCV. This includes `sqrt` , `if/else` `+`, `-` ...

I know I can use `forEach` to have access to each pixel avoiding the use of `at` and pointer arithmetic that may be inefficient.

Is there a function for this? What's the best way?

I expect something like

```
forEachInBoth(cv::Mat mat1, cv::Mat mat2,const Functor& operation)
```

Where `operation` takes one argument from each `cv::mat`

Comment: Can't you use `std::transform` taking advantage of `cv::Mat::begin()` and `cv::Mat::end()` ?

Comment: @paolo can I pass `begin()` of both matrices to `std::transform` ? I thought it would only receive one ... I'm checkin gthe doc :)